Convert Class Name from CamelCase to kebab-or-dash-case
I'm trying to find the logic in Magento (if it exists/is usable) that converts class name from Upper Camel Case -to-> Kebab Case (or spinal case, dash case, lisp case, caterpillar case, hyphen case).
In a module, I'm trying to refactor 9 CLI Command Classes (and more in the future) that extends from \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command :
class MyVeryCustomCommand extends MyAbstractCommand
{
    protected string $commandName = 'my-very-custom-command-';

I'm trying to remove this definition of name in each command by implementing getClassNameInKebabCase():
class MyAbstractCommand extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName(self::PREFIX . $this->getClassNameInKebabCase());
        // INSTEAD OF
        // $this->setName(self::PREFIX . $this->commandName);
    }

It would be even perfect if the logic is already somewhere in the framework !
(Maybe leveraging some convention that need the same string conversion)
Even if not, I think this function would be useful elsewhere, and is worth the 9*2 lines removed.
Secondary question : for the reverse function, could this php function be used ucfirst() ?

I believe you looking for \Laminas\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToDash.
Laminas is new name Zend framework used in Magento
code example can looks like
<?php

use Laminas\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToDash;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

/** @var CamelCaseToDash $filter */
$filter = $objectManager->get(CamelCaseToDash::class);

var_dump(strtolower($filter->filter('Test\CamelCaseToDash')));


Also, if you don't want dependencies you can do it with regexp
<?php
$camelCaseString = 'Test\CamelCaseToDash';

$camelCaseToDashRegexp = '/([a-z])([A-Z])/';
$dashString = preg_replace($camelCaseToDashRegexp, '$1-$2', $camelCaseString);
var_dump(strtolower($dashString));


any of this code will output string(23) "test\camel-case-to-dash"
And yes you can use ucfirst for revers operation
$camelCaseStringRevert = str_replace('-', '', ucfirst($dashString));
var_dump($camelCaseStringRevert);

or \Laminas\Filter\Word\DashToCamelCase filter

exactly what I needed, Thanks ! (and Thank you for the info about the new name Laminas)
